# How do I remove NaN from character array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, character, nan

Trying to remove NaN from character array in Matlab using cellfun, but am not having any luck. Error message says: Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was char instead.

I am trying to read-in data from a .csv file, and below is the relevant snippet of code:

```
clear all

%import atmospheric data in text format **TAFT**
fid_atm = fopen('C:\Filepath\file.csv');
atm = textscan(fid_atm,['%s%f%s%s%s',repmat('%',1,203)],'headerlines',1, 'delimiter', ','); %%Added Delimiter%%

%convert cell to character in atmospheric data
cell1 = char(atm{1,3});

cell1(cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(cell1)),cell1)) = []; %this line is where the error message occurs
```

I need to remove the NaN's from cell1 because in the next step I am converting time into seconds, but when I do that, the dimensions of the matrices do not agree:

```
%time into seconds
time_atm = str2num(cell1(:,1:2))*3600 + str2num(cell1(:,4:5))*60 + str2num(cell1(:,7:8));
```

So, since cellfun isn't working, how do I remove the NaNs from cell1? I think by removing the NaNs I get the dimensions to agree in the time_atm step.

Comment: should be:    cell1(cellfun(@(cell1) any(isnan(cell1)),cell1)) = [];